# what are the zend components using by magento2?

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, architecture

Magento2 now using zend framewok 1 ,zend framework 2 ,symfony etc.

I want to know what are the components taken from zend framewok 1 and components taken from zend framewok 2.

For example:

1. Zend_Db (from zend 1)
2. Zend_Json (from zend 2)
3. Zend_mvc(from Zend 1)

etc.

And also how much percent from each framework(not exactly..i know its difficult)

for example:

- zend framewok 1: 45 %
- zend framewok 2: 25 %
- symfony: 30%

update:through composer i cant identify which component using magento.

for example:
symfony/config or zend/config ( both components existed in composer)

Comment: You could probably work this out with the `composer show` command

Comment: @RobbieAverill  from that i can see 'zendframework/zend-console' & 'symfony/console ' etc.So its mean that magento using both console lib?

Comment: You will get more accurate results with pdepend: http://pdepend.org/

Comment: fyi, some Zend modules have been removed https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/#zend-framework

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick breakdown of the components:

All those are from Zend Framework 2:

```
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-code": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-server": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-soap": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-uri": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-crypt": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-console": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-text": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-view": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-json": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-form": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-di": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-serializer": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-log": "~2.4.6",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "~2.4.6",
```

This one is a fork of Zend Framework 1.12.16:

```
    "magento/zendframework1": "1.12.16",
```

The Symfony components are:

```
    "symfony/console": "~2.3 <2.7",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
    "symfony/process": "~2.1",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.6|~3.0.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "~2.6|~3.0.0",
    "symfony/config": "~2.0,>=2.0.5|~3.0.0",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "~2.3|~3.0.0",
    "symfony/filesystem": "~2.3|~3.0.0"
    "symfony/yaml": "~2.1|~3.0.0",
```

As David said, only the Console component is used in `app/code/Magento` the other components are used internally under `lib/internal/Magento/Framework` .

Regarding the percentage, a simple count of the occurences in Magento 2.1-rc1 gives you (excluding comments and `vendor` folder):

- ~1400 references to `Zend_` which is from ZF1
- ~800 references to `Zend\` which is from ZF2
- ~850 references to `Symfony`

Answer (score 1):

from symfony only the symfony console-component is used.

It's pretty hard to tell which components are used from zf1 and zf2, but magento already in-officially announced that they want to get rid of zf1 by the end of the year (if that helps).